# Xamarin DispatchKeyEvent not firing when phone screen is off

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin, bluetooth

My app plays music with a MediaPlayer, and I'm catching the MediaPrevious and MediaNext keycodes from a bluetooth headset by overriding DispatchKeyEvent

This works fine, until the phone locks, at which point DispatchKeyEvent is no longer called upon these bluetooth key presses.

Is there some way to enable this function while the screen is locked?  Is there another function I should be using instead?  I know this is possible because every music player I've ever used has had this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a MediaSession:

```
public class cb : MediaSession.Callback
{
    public override bool OnMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    var s = new MediaSession(ApplicationContext, "asdf");
    s.SetCallback(new cb());

    s.SetFlags(MediaSessionFlags.HandlesMediaButtons | MediaSessionFlags.HandlesTransportControls);
    s.Active = true;
}
```